# Hitting Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree)

Tags: xcode, macos, assertion, macos-high-sierra

On MacOS X High Sierra 10.13.4 & 10.13.5 I started encountering the following assertion and abort:

Assertion failed: (NSViewIsCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay() != currentlyBuildingLayerTree), function NSViewSetCurrentlyBuildingLayerTreeForDisplay, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1561.40.112/AppKit.subproj/NSView.m, line 14485

The assertion seems to always occur randomly on one of these three lines of code:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.courseWindowController showWindow:self];
        [[self.courseWindowController window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
        [[self.courseWindowController window] setParentWindow:mainWindow];
    });
```

Has anybody else experienced this and how have you resolved it?

Comment: Chances are you are doing something with an `NSView` or `NSWindow` off of the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

@robmayoff was right.  I was stopping a busy spinner off the main thread.  You can set the environment variable CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS=1 and it'll show you.

You can set the environment variable in Xcode -> Product Menu -> Scheme Submenu -> Edit Scheme...  Pick "Run" and in the environment variables section, you can set CA_ASSERT_MAIN_THREAD_TRANSACTIONS.  Then run the app in the debugger and you'll find the issue.